# Python and csv.writer: Open in every loop or keep open?

Tags: python, loops, csv

In my little python script I open a csv file, write a header to it, process a loop in which I open many other csv files to look in them and finally I write once per loop into the first csv:

```
import csv

with open(output_file, 'wb') as f:
    outfileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    # write header

for loop_file in a_list_of_files:
    with open(loop_file) as s:
        # calculate something on the file and write one line to f
```

Now is it better to keep f open (that is, indent the loop), or open it once peer loop? What's more pythonic/faster?

Comment: This is a question that will attract mostly answers that are based on preferences and thus does not belong on StackOverflow (perhaps on CodeReview), because you don't have a real problem ("my code doesn't work"/"how do I do this in that language"). That being said: in your loop, gather the data, add the data to a list and then at the end of your data-gathering loop, write the list of lists once to the outfile.

Comment: @OliverW. has a great suggestion for average datasets but doesn't scale to the really big stuff. All else equal, opening the output file once before the loop is preferred because the overhead of opening/flushing/closing the file is much less.

Comment: @tdelaney, for the really big stuff, one could add a check inside the loop to see when this buffer (the list) is "big enough" and then write to the file (or use a thread to do that check). I'm sure you knew, considering your reputation. Just adding it for future reference. Still believe this question is not suited for SO though.

Comment: @Oliver: You're talking about premature optimization, the root of all evil. tdelaney's suggestion is a good rule-of-thumb because minimizing OS calls is almost always a good practice with respect to improving the speed of execution of any program.

Comment: I totally misunderstood the question and retracted my close-vote. @tdelaney you might want to consider adding your comment as an answer, I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening and closing a file has a cost:

- On open, the file must be found in the file system.
- On close, the data must be flushed from the process to the system
- both operations call out to the operating system several times

so, it is generally preferable to open the file once before starting the processing loop instead of re-opening it per loop.

(update) Here is an example that writes the output file as you go but deletes it if there are other errors in processing (so you don't have partial results that look like full results).

```
import csv

with open(output_file, 'wb') as f:
    outfileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    # write header

    try:
        for loop_file in a_list_of_files:
            with open(loop_file) as s:
                # calculate something on the file and write one line to f
                outfileWriter.write(something)
    except:
        # close and delete the file. the ctx manager will try to close
        # the file again, but that's harmless.
        f.close()
        os.remove(output_file)
        raise
```

Comment: From the comments I learn that I'd better write out once at the end of the script instead of once per loop. Is this correct?

Comment: Personally, I would open the file above the for loop and write as I go. I'd also wrap the code in an exception handler that deletes the output file on error so that I don't have partial results. It all depends on your design goals, but that's a normal way to do it. I'll add  short example.